# Copying user account credentials in Windows

Tags: windows, credentials, microsoft-account

Say I have 2 Windows installation on the same machine.

How can I copy accounts from one to the other, so that file-rights are the same on the instances?

This is regular accounts, Microsoft accounts, ideally also groups.
(Windows 10 mainly)

Comment: I don't think you can copy the privileges on all folders in a system... the best way to achieve something similar is using a group and assigning the two users to the same group...

Comment: What I think is that if you have a user Bill in instance A who has access to a file, then if you create a Bill on instance B, it is not really the same Bill, and he won't have access to the file from B. I would think recreating groups is the same? I know if you look on the file from B. Bill A will have a cryptic name. You suggest I put that into a Group on B? Are you sure this is possible?

Comment: I think this cryptic name is the SID, which leads to the post below.  Though it doesn't have a direct solution for not jet created accounts.  It seems some groups have standard SIDs, so if you use one of these, it can help.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/439675/how-to-bind-old-users-sid-to-new-user-to-remain-ntfs-file-ownership-and-permiss

Comment: It seems it is impossible, because the SIDs contains a part which is unique for each instance.  The number of standard groups seems quite big, So it seems a good idea to reuse them (Or I have to take care to always have the same machine ID, or use some kind of domains)